# How to use django-el-pagination with filtering?

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I have a django Listview and i am using django-el-pagination's ajax endless pagination to paginate my results and it works well. The problem is I need to apply some filters to it and have no clue on how to do it.

Can i send parameters through GET to the view? Have searched a lot and seems like no one had this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Data is always returned in the `get_queryset()` function.

If you want to simply filter from the database, you can just return objects.

```
class IndexView(AjaxListView):
    template_name = '****'
    context_object_name = '****'
    page_template = '****'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return your_model.objects.filter(title='***').order_by('**')
```

Else if you want to get data from non-database, you need to implement a proxy accordding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104761/6700079).

If not,the pagination ajax will request all data, then slice it.The proxy make your data sliced while querying.

This is my filter that getting data from ElasticSearch.

```
class IndexView(AjaxListView):
    template_name = '****'
    context_object_name = '****'
    page_template = '****'

        def get_queryset(self):
    params = {}
    # get query params
        for item in self.request.GET.items():
            if item[0] == 'page' or item[0] == 'querystring_key':
                continue
            params[item[0]] = item[1]

        # no filter
        if len(params) == 0:
            return ****.objects.filter().order_by('-date')

        else:
            return ESResult(params)

class ESResult(object):

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def __len__(self):
        s = self.search_es()
        if s:
            s = s[:1]
            r = s.execute()
            return r['hits']['total']
        else:
            return 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        assert isinstance(item, slice)
        result = []
        s = self.search_es()

        if s:
            s = s[item.start:item.stop]   # slice before querying
            r = s.execute()

            for a in r.to_dict()['hits']['hits']:
                one = a['_source']
                one['id'] = int(a['_id'])
                result.append(one)

        return result

    def search_es():
        ...
        # filter request here
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The list object used by AjaxListView is defined by `get_queryset()` method. To filter the queryset based on the users input, you may refer to POST method:

```
from app.forms import BlogFilterForm

class Blog(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxListView):
    context_object_name = "posts"
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    page_template = 'blog/post_list.html'
    success_url = '/blog'

    def get_queryset(self): # define queryset
        queryset = Post.objects.all() # default queryset
        if self.request.method == 'POST': # check if the request method is POST
            form = BlogFilterForm(self.request.POST) # define form
            if form.is_valid(): 
                name = form.cleaned_data['name'] # retrieve data from the form
                if name:
                    queryset = queryset.filter(name=name) # filter queryset
        else:
            queryset = queryset
        return queryset 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Blog, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = BlogFilterForm() # define context to render the form on GET method
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # define post method
        return super(Blog, self).get(request, args, kwargs)
```

The endless pagination should work fine. 
[using filters with django-endless-pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220750/using-filters-with-django-endless-pagination)